# Cypher: Get info from deleted relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

`MATCH (n:Topic { mongoId: {_id} })-[r]-() DELETE n,r RETURN r;`

That returns the error 'Error: Relationship 1509 has been deleted'.

However, I need `r.mongoId` to delete entries in another database.

How do I do this with Neo4j 2.2.3?

I'm doing this through the [Seraph library](https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph).  Is there a way to collect a property, delete the relationships, and return the collection?

I just need this data:  `MATCH (n:Topic { mongoId: _id })-[r]-() RETURN COLLECT(r.mongoId);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `WITH` clause to alias the data you want to return before deleting the node and relationship. Something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Topic {mongoId: {_id} })-[r]-() 
WITH r.mongoId as docId, n,r 
DELETE n,r 
RETURN docId
```

Or you could break it up into two queries, one to retrieve the property you want, then the second to delete the relationship and node.

**EDIT**: you most likely want to specify a directed relationship to avoid duplicate `docId` properties returned:

```
MATCH (n:Topic {mongoId: {_id} })-[r]->()
...
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand your edit.  Duplicate id's aren't so bad.   But if I direct the relationship, I'll miss r in (n:)<-[r]-(), which would be an error.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: You are right - the usefulness of a directed relationship pattern depends on your data model. If your data model allows for both (:Topic)-[]->() and (:Topic)<-[]-(), then yes you will want an undirected pattern. Just realize there may be duplicated relationships / relationship properties returned (which you can filter out with the `DISTINCT` command).